# How to call a stored procedure in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I can't call a stored procedure in CodeIgniter. However, when I call the procedure directly in MySQL, it works. Why isn't it working when I call it in CodeIgniter?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_proc`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  declare name1 TEXT;
  declare id1 TEXT;
  select name,id into name1,id1 from my_tbl WHERE name='sam';
  select * from my_tbl;
  select name1,id1;
END
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are using the following way to call procedure.

```
$this->db->call_function('test_proc');
```

Its wrong. Only default procedures can be called using this method.
To call procedures defined by you, you have to go with

```
$this->db->query("call test_proc()");
```

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle procedured here is a simple way to call

```
 $rsponse = '';
    $s = oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, "begin packageName.procedureName(:bind1,:bind2,:bind3,:bind4,:bind5); end;");
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind1", $data['fieldOne'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind2", $data['fieldTwo'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind3", $data['fieldThre'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind4", $data['fieldFour'],300);
               oci_bind_by_name($s, ":bind4", $response,300);
               oci_execute($s, OCI_DEFAULT); 
echo $message;
```

In the above example procedure accept four arguments as input and one parameter as output. in case of direct calling procedure remove 'packageName.'
That's it...