# Codeigniter saving with Stored Procedure

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Good day. I'm trying to save with stored procedure. When I run directly from Sql Server it's working fine. But when i'm trying to run it from my Codeigniter it's not working. There is no error.

Here is My Codeigniter Controller Function :

```
public function save(){
        extract(populateform());
        $transno = $this->session->userdata('session_transno');
        $recdata = $this->session->userdata('session_date');
        $loginuser = $this->input->cookie("cookie_posweb_user");
        $this->modelmodel->queryhandle("[DeliveryReceiptInsert] '".$transno."', '".inggris_date($recdata)."',
                                    '".$loginuser."',
                                    '".implode(';', $LineNo).';'."','".implode(';', $ItemCode).';'."','".implode(';', $ExtraRemark).';'."',
                                    '".implode(';', $ExtraRemark2).';'."','".implode(';', $Quantity).';'."',
                                    '".implode(';', $recv_qty).';'."','".implode(';', $uom).';'."','".implode(';', $ext_rmrk).';'."'");

    }
```

Here is My Model

```
function queryhandle($query)
    {
        $this->db->query($query);
    }
```

And here is My Stored Procedure

```
USE [InventWeb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[DeliveryReceiptInsert]    Script Date: 10/26/2016 10:38:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeliveryReceiptInsert]
(
    --Header
    @DeliveryOrderTransNo as Varchar(32),
    @ReceivingDate as Datetime,
    @CreatedBy as varchar(32),
    --Detail
    @LineNo as Varchar(Max),
    @ItemCode as Varchar(Max),
    @ExtraRemark as Varchar(Max),
    @ExtraRemark2 as Varchar(Max),
    @Quantity as Varchar(Max),
    @QuantityReceived as Varchar(Max),
    @UOMCode as Varchar(Max),
    @ExtraRemarkReceive as Varchar(Max)
)
as
Begin
    --Variable

    declare @DeliveryOrderDocumentNo as varchar(32)
    declare @FromCustomer as Varchar(32)
    declare @ToCustomer as Varchar(32)
    declare @ExternalDocumentNo as Varchar(32)
    declare @CategoryCode as Varchar(4)
    declare @ETADate as Datetime
    declare @ShippingDocumentNo as Varchar(32)
    declare @ShippingDate as Datetime
    declare @ShippedBy as Varchar(16)
    declare @Remark as Varchar(64)
    declare @Remark2 as Varchar(64)



    select 
           @DeliveryOrderDocumentNo = DocumentNo,   
           @FromCustomer = FromCustomerCode,
           @ToCustomer   = ToCustomerCode,
           @ExternalDocumentNo = ExternalDocumentNo,
           @CategoryCode = CategoryCode,
           @ETADate = ETADate,
           @ShippingDocumentNo = ShippingDocumentNo,
           @ShippedBy = ShippedBy,
           @ShippingDate = ShippingDate,
           @Remark      = Remark,
           @Remark2     = Remark2

    from TMP_deliveryorder where TransactionNo = ''+@DeliveryOrderTransNo+''


    Declare @SerieCode as Varchar(32)
    Declare @TransNo as Varchar(32)
    Declare @DocumentNo as Varchar(32)
    Declare @TempCreatedBy as Varchar(32)
    Declare @TempCreatedDate as DateTime
    Declare @Posisi as Int
    Declare @Baris as Int
    Declare @Mulai as Int
    Declare @Temp as Varchar(32)
    Declare @TotalRow as Int
    Declare @TransNoDetail as Varchar(32)
    Declare @KumpTransNoDetail as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @ErrorMsg Varchar(Max)
    Declare @Sql as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @Find as Varchar(1)
    Declare @TempLineNo as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @TempXremark as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @TempXremark2 as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @TempXremarkReceipt as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @TempQty as Varchar(Max)    
    Declare @TempQtyReceipt as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @TempUOMCode as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @TempItemCode as Varchar(Max)
    Declare @DoTransNo as Varchar(32)
    --Variable

    --Checking Parameter
    --If (@DocumentNo Is Null) set @DocumentNo = ''
    If (@ReceivingDate Is Null) set @ReceivingDate = GETDATE()
    If (@DeliveryOrderDocumentNo Is Null) set @DeliveryOrderDocumentNo = ''
    If (@FromCustomer Is Null) set @FromCustomer = ''
    If (@ToCustomer Is Null) set @ToCustomer = ''
    If (@ExternalDocumentNo Is Null) set @ExternalDocumentNo = ''
    If (@CategoryCode Is Null) set @CategoryCode = ''
    If (@ETADate Is Null) set @ETADate = GETDATE()
    If (@ShippingDocumentNo Is Null) set @ShippingDocumentNo = ''
    If (@ShippingDate Is Null) set @ShippingDate = GETDATE()
    If (@ShippedBy Is Null) set @ShippedBy = ''
    If (@Remark Is Null) set @Remark = ''
    If (@Remark2 Is Null) set @Remark2 = ''
    If (@CreatedBy Is Null) set @CreatedBy = ''
    If (@LineNo Is Null) set @LineNo = ''
    If (@ItemCode Is Null) set @ItemCode = ''
    If (@ExtraRemark Is Null) set @ExtraRemark = ''
    If (@ExtraRemark2 Is Null) set @ExtraRemark2 = ''
    If (@Quantity Is Null) set @Quantity = ''
    If (@QuantityReceived Is Null) set @QuantityReceived = ''
    If (@UOMCode Is Null) set @UOMCode = ''
    If (@ExtraRemarkReceive Is Null) set @ExtraRemarkReceive = ''
    If (@ReceivingDate = '') set @ReceivingDate = GETDATE()
    If (@DeliveryOrderDocumentNo = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Delivery Order DocumentNo',11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@FromCustomer = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter From Customer Code', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@ToCustomer = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter To Customer Code', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@CategoryCode = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Category Code', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@ETADate = '') set @ETADate = GETDATE()
    If (@ShippingDocumentNo = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Shipping Document Code', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@ShippingDate = '') set @ShippingDate = GETDATE()
    If (@ShippedBy = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Shipped By', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@CreatedBy = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Created By', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@LineNo = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Line No', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@ItemCode = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Item Code', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@Quantity = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Quantity', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@QuantityReceived = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter Quantity Received', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If (@UOMCode = '') 
        Begin
            Raiserror('Invalid Parameter UOM Code', 11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If Not Exists (Select CustomerCode From Customer Where CustomerCode = @FromCustomer)
        Begin
            Raiserror('From Customer Code Not Found',11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If Not Exists (Select CustomerCode From CustomerSetup Where CustomerCode = @ToCustomer)
        Begin
            Raiserror('Wrong To Customer Code',11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    If Not Exists (Select CategoryCode From DeliveryOrderCategory Where CategoryCode = @CategoryCode)
        Begin
            Raiserror('Category Code Not Found',11,-1,-1)
            Return
        End
    --Checking Parameter


    --Set Formula for Transaction No 
    set @SerieCode = (Select SerieCode From CustomerSetup With(READPAST) Where CustomerCode = @ToCustomer)
    --Set Formula for Transaction No


    Begin Transaction
        --Set Transaction No for Header
        Set @TransNo = dbo.TransactionNumber3 ( 'TRANS', 'DOR', 'TRANS', @SerieCode, @ToCustomer )
        --Set Transaction No for Header


        --Save Transaction No Header to TempNumberSeries
        Insert Into TempNumberSeries Values (@TransNo)
        --Save Transaction No Header to TempNumberSeries


        --Set Document No for Header
        Set @DocumentNo = dbo.TransactionNumber3 ( 'DOC', 'DOR', @CategoryCode, @SerieCode, @ToCustomer )
        --Set Document No for Header

        Set @DoTransNo = (Select TransactionNo From DeliveryOrder With(NoLock) Where DocumentNo = @DeliveryOrderDocumentNo)

        --Save Document No Header to TempNumberSeries
        Insert Into TempNumberSeries Values (@DocumentNo)
        --Save Document No Header to TempNumberSeries


        --Save Header
        Insert Into DeliveryReceipt(TransactionNo, DocumentNo, ReceivingDate,
            ShippingDocumentNo, ShippedBy, ShippingDate, DeliveryOrderDocumentNo,
            FromCustomerCode, ToCustomerCode, ExternalDocumentNo, CategoryCode,
            Remark, Remark2, ETADate, SendStatus, PostingBy, PostingDate, PostingStatus, 
            CreatedDate, CreatedBy, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy)
        Values (@TransNo, @DocumentNo, @ReceivingDate,
            @ShippingDocumentNo, @ShippedBy, @ShippingDate, @DeliveryOrderDocumentNo,
            @FromCustomer, @ToCustomer, @ExternalDocumentNo, @CategoryCode,
            @Remark, @Remark2, @ETADate, 0, '', '', 0, GETDATE(),   @CreatedBy, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy)
        --Save Header


        Execute ActivityLog_Insert  @TransNo, @ShippingDocumentNo, '', 'DeliveryReceipt', 'INSERT', @CreatedBy, @ToCustomer

         IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES   
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'dbo'  AND TABLE_NAME = N'TableDOR')
                    BEGIN
                      DROP Table TableDOR;
                    END


        --Create Table Pembantu
        Create Table TableDOR
        (
            xId Int,
            xData varchar(32)
        )
        --Create Table Pembantu


        --Pecah String Item
        set @Posisi = 1
        set @Baris = 1
        set @Mulai = 1
        While Len(@ItemCode) >= @Posisi
        Begin
            If LTrim(RTrim(SubString(@ItemCode, @Posisi, 1))) = ';'
                Begin
                    --Get Data
                    set @Temp = LTRIM(RTRIM(SubString(@ItemCode, @Mulai, @Posisi - @Mulai)))
                    --Insert Data to Tabel Pembantu
                    Insert Into TableDOR Values (@Baris, @Temp)
                    --Check Item
                    If not Exists (Select ItemCode From Item With(READPAST) Where ItemCode = @Temp)
                        Begin
                            raiserror('Invalid Item Code',11,-1,-1)
                            rollback
                            return
                        End

                    --Set Baris +1
                    set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                    set @Baris = @Baris + 1
                    set @Temp = ''
                End

            set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
        End
        --Pecah String Item


        --Looping Sebanyak Baris
        set @TotalRow  = @Baris - 1
        set @Posisi = 1
        set @Baris = 1
        While @TotalRow >= @Baris
            Begin
            --Pecah String LineNo
                set @Find = 'N'
                set @Posisi = 1
                set @Mulai = 1                  
                while len(ltrim(rtrim(@LineNo))) >= @Posisi
                    Begin
                        If SubString(@LineNo, @Posisi, 1) = ';'
                            Begin
                                --Get Data
                                set @TempLineNo = substring(@LineNo, 1, @Posisi - 1)
                                set @LineNo = substring(@LineNo, @Posisi + 1, len(@LineNo) - @Posisi)
                                set @Find = 'Y'
                            End                             
                        set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                        set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
                        if @find = 'Y'
                            break
                        else
                            continue
                    End
                --Pecah String LineNo


                --Pecah String Xremark
                set @Find = 'N'
                set @Posisi = 1
                set @Mulai = 1                  
                while len(ltrim(rtrim(@ExtraRemark))) >= @Posisi
                    Begin
                        If SubString(@ExtraRemark, @Posisi, 1) = ';'
                            Begin
                                --Get Data
                                set @TempXremark = substring(@ExtraRemark, 1, @Posisi - 1)
                                set @ExtraRemark = substring(@ExtraRemark, @Posisi + 1, len(@ExtraRemark) - @Posisi)
                                set @Find = 'Y'
                            End                             
                        set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                        set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
                        if @find = 'Y'
                            break
                        else
                            continue
                    End
                --Pecah String Xremark


                --Pecah String Xremark2
                set @Find = 'N'
                set @Posisi = 1
                set @Mulai = 1                  
                while len(ltrim(rtrim(@ExtraRemark2))) >= @Posisi
                    Begin
                        If SubString(@ExtraRemark2, @Posisi, 1) = ';'
                            Begin
                                --Get Data
                                set @TempXremark2 = substring(@ExtraRemark2, 1, @Posisi - 1)
                                set @ExtraRemark2 = substring(@ExtraRemark2, @Posisi + 1, len(@ExtraRemark2) - @Posisi)
                                set @Find = 'Y'
                            End                             
                        set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                        set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
                        if @find = 'Y'
                            break
                        else
                            continue
                    End
                --Pecah String Xremark2


                --Pecah String XremarkReceipt
                set @Find = 'N'
                set @Posisi = 1
                set @Mulai = 1                  
                while len(ltrim(rtrim(@ExtraRemarkReceive))) >= @Posisi
                    Begin
                        If SubString(@ExtraRemarkReceive, @Posisi, 1) = ';'
                            Begin
                                --Get Data
                                set @TempXremarkReceipt = substring(@ExtraRemarkReceive, 1, @Posisi - 1)
                                set @ExtraRemarkReceive = substring(@ExtraRemarkReceive, @Posisi + 1, len(@ExtraRemarkReceive) - @Posisi)
                                set @Find = 'Y'
                            End                             
                        set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                        set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
                        if @find = 'Y'
                            break
                        else
                            continue
                    End
                --Pecah String XremarkReceipt


                --Pecah String Qty
                set @Find = 'N'
                set @Posisi = 1
                set @Mulai = 1                  
                while len(ltrim(rtrim(@Quantity))) >= @Posisi
                    Begin
                        If SubString(@Quantity, @Posisi, 1) = ';'
                            Begin
                                --Get Data
                                set @TempQty = substring(@Quantity, 1, @Posisi - 1)
                                set @Quantity = substring(@Quantity, @Posisi + 1, len(@Quantity) - @Posisi)
                                set @Find = 'Y'
                            End                             
                        set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                        set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
                        if @find = 'Y'
                            break
                        else
                            continue
                    End
                --Pecah String Qty


                --Pecah String Qty Receipt
                set @Find = 'N'
                set @Posisi = 1
                set @Mulai = 1                  
                while len(ltrim(rtrim(@QuantityReceived))) >= @Posisi
                    Begin
                        If SubString(@QuantityReceived, @Posisi, 1) = ';'
                            Begin
                                --Get Data
                                set @TempQtyReceipt = substring(@QuantityReceived, 1, @Posisi - 1)
                                set @QuantityReceived = substring(@QuantityReceived, @Posisi + 1, len(@QuantityReceived) - @Posisi)
                                set @Find = 'Y'
                            End                             
                        set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                        set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
                        if @Find = 'Y'
                            break
                        else
                            continue
                    End
                --Pecah String Qty Receipt


                --Pecah String UOM Code
                set @Find = 'N'
                set @Posisi = 1
                set @Mulai = 1                  
                while len(ltrim(rtrim(@UOMCode))) >= @Posisi
                    Begin
                        If SubString(@UOMCode, @Posisi, 1) = ';'
                            Begin
                                --Get Data
                                set @TempUOMCode = substring(@UOMCode, 1, @Posisi - 1)
                                set @UOMCode = substring(@UOMCode, @Posisi + 1, len(@UOMCode) - @Posisi)
                                set @Find = 'Y'
                            End                             
                        set @Mulai = @Posisi + 1
                        set @Posisi = @Posisi + 1
                        if @Find = 'Y'
                            break
                        else
                            continue
                    End
                --Pecah String UOM Code


                --Create Trans No Detail
                Set @TransNoDetail = dbo.TransactionNumber3 ( 'TRANS', 'DORD', 'TRANS', @SerieCode, @ToCustomer )
                --Create Trans No Detail


                --Save Trans No Detail To TempNoSerie
                Insert Into TempNumberSeries Values (@TransNoDetail)
                --Save Trans No Detail To TempNoSerie
                Execute UpdateTransactionNumber 'TRANS', 'DORD', 'TRANS', @SerieCode, 1, @ToCustomer
                --Get Item Code 
                set @TempItemCode = (Select xData From TableDOR Where xId = @Baris)
                --Get Item Code 

                Declare @IntLineNo Int
                Set @IntLineNo = Cast(@TempLineNo as Int)

                --Save Detail
                Insert Into DeliveryReceiptDetail (TransactionNo, [LineNo], ItemCode, ExtraRemark, 
                    ExtraRemark2, Quantity, QuantityReceived, UOMCode, ExtraRemarkReceipt, DeliveryReceiptTransNo, 
                    CreatedDate, CreatedBy, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy)
                Values (@TransNoDetail, @IntLineNo, @TempItemCode, @TempXremark,
                    @TempXremark2, @TempQty, @TempQtyReceipt, @TempUOMCode, @TempXremarkReceipt, @TransNo,
                    GETDATE(), @CreatedBy, GETDATE(), @CreatedBy)
                --Save Detail


                --Set @Baris
                set @Baris = @Baris + 1
                --Set @Baris
            End
        --Looping Sebanyak Baris


        --Delete TempNumberSerie
        Delete TempNumberSeries Where NumberSeriesCode = @TransNo
        Delete TempNumberSeries Where NumberSeriesCode = @DocumentNo
        Begin Try
            Set @Sql = 'Delete TempNumberSeries Where NumberSeriesCode in (' + @KumpTransNoDetail + ')'
            Exec(@sql)
        End Try
        Begin Catch
            set @ErrorMsg = (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())
            set @ErrorMsg = 'Delete TempNumberSeries For Detail Failed!' + Char(13) + 'Please Call Your IT.' + Char(13) + @ErrorMsg
            Raiserror('%s',11,-1,@ErrorMsg)
            Rollback
            Return
        End Catch   
        --Delete TempNumberSerie


        --Update NoSerieSetup 
        Execute UpdateTransactionNumber 'TRANS', 'DOR', 'TRANS', @SerieCode, 1, @ToCustomer
        Execute UpdateTransactionNumber 'DOC', 'DOR', @CategoryCode, @SerieCode, 1, @ToCustomer
        --Update NoSerieSetup 


        --Execute ActivityLog_Insert  @DoTransNo, @DeliveryOrderDocumentNo, '', 'TMP_DeliveryOrder', 'DELETE', @CreatedBy, @ToCustomer


        --Return Trans No Header
        select @TransNo as TransactionNo, @DocumentNo as DocumentNo

        --Return Trans No Header
    Commit Transaction
End
```

And this how i run it directly from Sql Server

```
[DeliveryReceiptInsert] 'DO-DI-GCZAR10-407', '2016-11-01', '1500676', '1000;2000;3000;','P160012;P160013;P160014;',';;;', ';;;','1.00000000000000000000;1.00000000000000000000;1.00000000000000000000;', '1;1;1;','PCS;PCS;PCS;','12;12;12;'
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201045/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-codeigniter

Comment: i give up with this. So i re-create the query in my php