# How to get result from MSSQL stored procedure with temp table in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-functions

I am using Codeigniter 3.1 and I wanna get result from a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server. but I can't get any result

Stored Procedure Script:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SendPost_All_Periodic]
@DateAs nvarchar(10),
@DateTo nvarchar(10)   
as
begin


 DECLARE @temptable TABLE (MsgDate nvarchar(10),Saat tinyint)

 INSERT INTO @temptable
 SELECT MsgDate,CAST(LEFT(MsgTime, 2) AS int) as Saat2
 FROM  dbo.TMessage
 Where MsgDate>=@DateAs and MsgDate<=@DateTo

 Select Saat,count(Saat)as CountSend from @temptable
 group by Saat
 order by Saat

end
```

My PHP Code:

```
$DateAs = "2017/01/02";

$DateTo = "2017/01/03";

$result = $this->db->query("SendPost_All_Periodic '{$DateAs}', '{$DateTo}'");

print_r($publishtime->result_array());
```

But when I use from this method for normal select, This code create result, but I can't get result than select from TempTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error messages when you try to execute your code?

Based on the code you have provided, you might have a few problems and the call might depend upon which database driver you are using in your config (ex: pdo).  First, in your `print_r` statement, you are calling a variable that seemingly doesn't exist.  So, give this a quick try:

```
print_r($result->result_array());
```

Also, the way you are passing in your parameters might cause an issue (the single quotes).  Give these both a try and see which works.

**Method One:**

```
$result = $this->db->query("SendPost_All_Periodic {$DateAs}, {$DateTo}");
print_r($result->result_array());
```

**Method Two:**

```
$result = $this->db->query("EXEC SendPost_All_Periodic @DateAs='$DateAs', @DateTo='$DateTo'");
print_r($result->result_array());
```

Hopefully this helps.  If so, let me know which one works.  If not, see if this Stackoverflow article points you in the right direction: [How to call a stored procedure in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201045/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-codeigniter)